# Скрыть все активные формы

Tags: c#, winforms

Помогите переделать данный код.
Сейчас он скрывает все формы меняя их Visible на false
Но, я же хочу переделать чтобы было использовано:

```
Window windowstate = formwindowstate.Minimized;
Window WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            bool visible = !Visible;
            Form topForm = null;
            foreach (Form form in Application.OpenForms)
            {
                if (form.Modal)
                {
                    form.Opacity = visible ? 1 : 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    form.Visible = visible;
                }
                topForm = form;
            }
            if (visible)
                topForm?.Activate();
        }
```

Comment: Ну, так используйте этот код. В чем вопрос то?

Comment: Если бы я хотел использовать этот код, я бы его и использовал, хочу сменить структуру выполнения этого всего дела, ибо когда используешь Visible, пропадает программа как окно, а мне этого не нужно. @Bulson

Comment: Не нужно скрывать окно программы — не скрывайте его. Например, проверяйте имя формы, прежде чем её скрыть. А скрывать можно еще и так: `form.Hide();`

Comment: @Ulysses Понимаете в чём дело, у меня не 1-на форма. А данный код работает как раз для всех форм. Если вы не готовы помогать, зачем тогда отвечаете тут?

Comment: Тогда сформулируйте корректно постановку задачи. Что дано, что следует получить. Многое, что для вас возможно кажется очевидным, осталось за кадром.

Comment: @Ulysses В данный момент представлен код, который отлично работает, но, он работает не так как мне нужно. Тут в коде используется видимость Visible, я же хочу чтобы было `Window windowstate = formwindowstate.Minimized;
Window WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;`

Answer (score 0):

По куску вашего кода сложно догадаться обо всех тонкостях поставленной задачи. Посмотрите простенький пример как можно минимизировать/восстанавливать формы для MDI.
Form1 — MDI-контейнер. В ней MenuStrip с двумя пунктами меню. Один открывает новый документ(дочернюю форму), другой — минимизирует/восстанавливает дочерние формы.
Form2 — класс дочерней формы. Я просто добавил еще одну форму к проекту, без изменений.

Листинг Form1.cs

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace FormMinimization
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private int documentCounter;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Width = 800;
            this.Height = 600;
            this.MinimumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(300, 200);
        }

        private void openWindowToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var newForm = new Form2();
            newForm.Text = $"Document {documentCounter++}";
            newForm.Width = 400;
            newForm.Height = 300;
            newForm.MdiParent = this;
            newForm.Show();
        }

        private void minimizeToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bool minimize = minimizeToolStripMenuItem.Text == "Minimize all documents" ? true : false;

            foreach (Form form in this.MdiChildren)
            { 
                if (minimize)
                    form.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
                else
                    form.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
            }

            minimizeToolStripMenuItem.Text = minimize ? "Restore all documents" : "Minimize all documents";
        }
    }
}
```

Листинг Form1.Designer.cs

```
namespace FormMinimization
{
    partial class Form1
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.menuStrip1 = new System.Windows.Forms.MenuStrip();
            this.openWindowToolStripMenuItem = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();
            this.minimizeToolStripMenuItem = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();
            this.menuStrip1.SuspendLayout();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // menuStrip1
            // 
            this.menuStrip1.Items.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem[] {
            this.openWindowToolStripMenuItem,
            this.minimizeToolStripMenuItem});
            this.menuStrip1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
            this.menuStrip1.Name = "menuStrip1";
            this.menuStrip1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(784, 24);
            this.menuStrip1.TabIndex = 0;
            this.menuStrip1.Text = "menuStrip1";
            // 
            // openWindowToolStripMenuItem
            // 
            this.openWindowToolStripMenuItem.Name = "openWindowToolStripMenuItem";
            this.openWindowToolStripMenuItem.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(106, 20);
            this.openWindowToolStripMenuItem.Text = "Open document";
            this.openWindowToolStripMenuItem.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.openWindowToolStripMenuItem_Click);
            // 
            // minimizeToolStripMenuItem
            // 
            this.minimizeToolStripMenuItem.Name = "minimizeToolStripMenuItem";
            this.minimizeToolStripMenuItem.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(146, 20);
            this.minimizeToolStripMenuItem.Text = "Minimize all documents";
            this.minimizeToolStripMenuItem.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.minimizeToolStripMenuItem_Click);
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(784, 561);
            this.Controls.Add(this.menuStrip1);
            this.IsMdiContainer = true;
            this.MainMenuStrip = this.menuStrip1;
            this.Name = "Form1";
            this.Text = "Program";
            this.menuStrip1.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.menuStrip1.PerformLayout();
            this.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.PerformLayout();

        }

        #endregion

        private System.Windows.Forms.MenuStrip menuStrip1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem openWindowToolStripMenuItem;
        private System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem minimizeToolStripMenuItem;
    }
}
```

Comment: Стесняюсь спросить, а зачем так всё усложнять? Ведь я в примере не столь большой код привёл, а вы тут целую систему сделали.

Comment: Это небольшой пример организации MDI. Собственно минимизация/восстановление форм — в методе `minimizeToolStripMenuItem_Click`.